# Javascript: Call variable from concatenated strings

Tags: javascript

I've got a little problem with a JavaScript function (I'm pretty new to JavaScript in general) to which I pass a String(cat) and a JSON string (args) I guess you know what I like to achieve: if I pass foo as 'cat' I'd like to parse args.foo:

```
function addchardata(cat, args){
    var data= JSON.parse(args+'.'+cat);    ///this does not work...
}
```

Comment: You do realize that creates invalid JSON, right?

Comment: A small example of what you would like to achieve would be helpful. It's not that easy to guess what you want as output

Comment: "I guess you know what i like to achieve" Nope, pretend I'm not clairvoyant    and explain explicitly, please.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ah ok, sorry: What i meant was: "JSON.parse(args.one)" works the way I want it (delivering the data array for a highcharts chart, one is a jsf Callback-Parameter), but what can I do to get the same result by passing args and a String "one" to a function?

Comment: @MikeBalthasar: The answers to the linked question show you how to do that. Short version: `args[cat]` will access the `one` property on `args` if `cat` contains the string `"one"`. E.g., `var cat = "one"; console.log(args[cat]);` and `console.log(args.one);` both access the same property.